# Django. Структура проекта

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

[Здесь](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/tutorial/quickstart/) создаются директории:

```
tutorial/tutorial/quickstart
tutorial/tutorial
```

Мне не ясно, почему такая дикая вложенность. Вроде говорится, про "правильную" архитектуру. Но в чём привильность не ясно. Плюс, не ясно, что есть `quickstrat`, а что есть `tutorial`. Можно пример из боевого проекта?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Сначала о разнице между `tutorial` и `quickstart`. К сожалению, у джанго путаница с терминологией, точнее она неочевидная.

`tutorial` - это проект (project) в терминологии django. Это целостное приложение (в смысле ПО или программный продукт), т.е. его можно запустить. `quickstart` - это в терминологии джанго app (application), по сути это модуль, который можно повторно использовать подключая в джанго проект, application сам по себе не может быть запущен. django project - это набор django applications + конфигурация (главной частью которого является как раз список applications, которые используются в проекте).

В более менее сложном проекте, будет много django applications. Иногда бывает несколько джанго проектов, например, если есть клиент и сервер, то их имеет смысл делать отдельными проектами.

Что касается `tutorial` верхнего уровня, то это просто корневая папка проекта. Они будет корневой папкой в системе контроля версий. В ней будут файлы типа README, каталог docs, какие-нибудь скрипты, которые используются на CI или в развертывании, т.е. то что является частью проекта, но не есть частью django приложения.

Чтоб лучше уловить разницу: `tutorial/tutorial` будет пакетом верхенго уровня, который входит в PYTHONPATH при запуске приложения. А в корневой папке лежит `manage.py`, который совсем не нужен в `runtime`, когда приложение будет развертываться в боевом режиме. Т.е. в корневом каталоге не будет `__init__.py` и он не является пакетом доступным приложению в runtime.